# Where do the buffer values come from when rendering?

Tags: rendering, depth-buffer

In the textbook I am reading, it talks about fragment tests that are performed when rendering.

All of these tests involve comparing the current fragment x value (x can be alpha, color, etc.) with a corresponding buffer value, and doing something in case the test passes. The test is usually a comparison between those two values (for example, >=, <=, etc.).

What I cannot understand is where do these buffer values come from in the first place?

Are these previous values? If so, what do the current values have to do with previously calculated values?

I don't even know what to search in google for this topic. Sorry if it is a total starter question. I am currently reading about rendering for the first time

Answer (score 1):

The "buffer" values are the ones previously written to the destination buffer. For example, for a depth test, this would be a value in the depth buffer.

That value was either put there when you cleared the depth buffer at the start of the frame, or by writing the result of a previous fragment that itself passed the depth test.

This is similar for blending tests (which operate on the color buffer) and stencil tests (which operate on the stencil buffer). You put initial default values there at the start of the frame (most of the time), and potentially modify what is in them after each fragment operation.